# Can the adding of xmp:ModifyDate be avoided in itext7?

Tags: java, itext7

When creating a PDF/A from scratch with itext7, the following always gets added to the XMP metadata:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"
    xmlns:pdfaExtension="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/extension/"
    xmlns:pdfaSchema="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/schema#"
    xmlns:pdfaProperty="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/property#"
    xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
    xmlns:pdfuaid="http://www.aiim.org/pdfua/ns/id/"
    xmlns:pdfaid="http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/"
  dc:format="application/pdf"
  pdf:Producer="iTextÂ® 7.0.3-SNAPSHOT Â©2000-2017 iText Group NV (AGPL-version)"
  xmp:CreateDate="2017-05-09T15:02:05+02:00"
  xmp:ModifyDate="2017-05-09T15:02:05+02:00"
  pdfaid:part="2"
  pdfaid:conformance="A">
```

I need to explicitly NOT set a xmp:ModifyDate. 
I've tried deleting it from the Catalog, but to no avail:

```
PdfADocument pdf = new PdfADocument(writer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_2A, OutputIntent);
Document document = new Document(pdf);
... add content to pdf ...
pdf.getCatalog().remove(PdfName.ModDate);
document.close();
writer.close();
```

But still, the xmp:ModifyDate shows up in the XMP metadata.

Is there a way to make sure that only the xmp:CreateDate is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you two ways of avoiding adding `ModifyDate` to metadata.

The **first** one if via the `PdfDocumentInfo` right before closing the document:

```
doc.getDocumentInfo().setMoreInfo(PdfName.ModDate.getValue(), null);
doc.close();
```

The **second** way is more flexible and is done via overriding `updateXmpMetadata` method in `PdfDocument`/`PdfADocument`:

```
@Override
protected void updateXmpMetadata() {
    // Do not forget to call the method of the base class!
    super.updateXmpMetadata();
    try {
        XMPMeta meta = XMPMetaFactory.parseFromBuffer(getXmpMetadata(true));
        // Here we remove the unwanted entry from the metadata
        meta.deleteProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP, PdfConst.ModifyDate);
        setXmpMetadata(meta);
    } catch (XMPException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thx Alexey! In order to keep the XMP and DocumentInfo consistent, it is necessary to use both ways :-)